# What is the best known algorithm of cross-matching events to a user?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-science

**Question**

Suppose I have certain amount of **events** of different types. I don't have user entity in my data, only events. Every type of event has info about event itself and some **uids**  which are user identifiers who caused or is a target of such event.

The task is to produce **users** from a bunch of ungrouped events. To say it different - we must group events by uids.

For simplicity we can describe a user as a set of uids which identifies group of events.

To have the ability to perform such cross-matching we will require that **some of our events has more than one uid**. This is needed for ability of grouping events of different types.

What are the best know algorithms which performs this task? I think that this is rather common task for big projects which are connected with different sources of informations about their users and which want to keep track of user's actions inside such big distributed system which doesn't share any common database.

**Example**

```
events = [
    {uid1:1,uid2:'uid2'},
    {uid1:1},
    {uid3:'uid3'}
]
```

After applying the algorithm to this data, I expect it will produce the following output

```
users = {
    {1, 'uid2', None}: [{uid1:1,uid2:'uid2'}, {uid1:1}],
    {None, None, 'uid3'}: [{uid3:'uid3'}] 
}
```

**My thoughts**
The event space can be represented as Discrete Linear Space and the algorithm will represent a factorization of this space on subsets. All elements of one subset should have non-zero projection on the user vector.

This sounds like an overkill for this problem, but I really didn't found any examples how people solve such tasks.

**UPD**
Created naive algorithm for this question. https://github.com/bl17zar/pygrouper

Comment: From your description this doesn't sounds like it would be a very difficult problem to solve, so I suspect there are complications that are not obvious. Can you elaborate with a few examples?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError added more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created naive implementation for this question. I am planning to upgrade this soon.
https://github.com/bl17zar/pygrouper

Answer (score 0):

That sounds to me like the Connected Components of the bipartite graph formed by the event to UID relation. This is the discrete solution.

If more than one user can produce events with the same UID as another, then the UIDs don't correspond to users but rather mixtures of users and to recover the users one would have to do inference on some type of model. Similar to how LDA infers topics from a document-term matrix. Except here it is users from a event-uid matrix.

Comment: yes it's a good note. I thought about it but for the start I assumed that all the uids are unique per uid type and generated only once. If this doesn't hold I would need to make some prioritization rules among uids or just not perform match If I have contradictions.